# How to download macOS High Sierra from the Mojave App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, mojave

I use the beta of macOS Mojave and I want to download High Sierra for another install.

I don't find it in the new App Store, maybe because the update of the OS is now in the System Preferences.

I try the link from the online version: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12 but the Download button is disabled.

Any idea to download it?

Comment: I'll presume you have no VM capability, no other Mac for my answer. If you have the others, you can just download it from a non-mojave OS.

Comment: No VM indeed. And it's for another mac whose hard drive is dead, so no recovery. And i want to keep Mojave.

Comment: You still can run recovery with a dead internal HD. no worries keeping this open/no answer selected -  just wanted to give you options if you really needed the install more than you needed to keep Mojave around. I would expect at some point Apple will light up that specific download on the new App Store - even it if’s when the general release is shipped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In previous versions of the beta this was not possible.  But in the latest release (as of 9/15/18) it is possible to use direct links to open the download page.

This links can be found on [Apple's *How To Download* pages](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475).

Here are the direct links for a some of them:

- [Big Sur](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132?mt=12)
- [Catalina](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?mt=12)
- [Mojave](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12)
- [High Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12)
- [Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12)
- [El Capitan](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12)
- [Yosemite](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=915041082&mt=12)

All other OS can be purchased from Apple directly and are not in the App Store.

Comment: What is the path where the download is present ?

Answer (score 5):

I would elaborate each of the steps given below, but this would be difficult without knowing more about your current partitioning and the model/year of your Mac.

1. Shrink the partition containing Mojava and add a new `jhfs+` partition.
2. Boot to internet recovery and install the version of macOS that came with your Mac.
3. If necessary, upgrade the current macOS.
4. Download High Sierra from the App Store.
5. (Optional) Remove the new partition and reclaim the free space.

Answer (score 2):

The erase and install process is always an option since the recovery HD will offer to download the latest shipping OS. You could always connect an external USB drive and boot to internet recovery and install a shipping OS to the external - leaving Mojave running on the main storage. Then you'll have a shipping version of the OS to download the installer if that's really what you need instead of just a quick wipe and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't let you download an OS that's earlier than the one you have on your mac. You need a mac running High Sierra or older to be able to download from the app store.