# How to get a clean installation copy of mac os High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, install

I have tried every combination of question and filter stating that I needed a full download of High Sierra. I need to do a clean install on another Mac I have, but every time I get the same download of approx 22MB instead of the ~5GB full install version.  I appreciate any help you can provide.  I never had this issue before they released Mojave, probably just a coincidence.

Comment: Check the link posted on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos - works for me from Mojave to DL the full 5GB version

Comment: why would it stop at 22 meg ?? no reason for that. unless you are downloading some update. So what is the link for download you are using.

Comment: try this link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12

Comment: or this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336634/46541